# Subdivided bibliographies by custom citation command

Tags: biblatex

I'm using a custom cite command and would like a bibliography which only includes entries cited with the custom cite command. I have a reference list for uncited items using `notcategory=cited` and would like something similar for entries having been called using my `\customcite`. I had a look in the biblatex documentation but I couldn't figure it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{customciteentry,
  author    = {Customcite},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
  keywords  = {hello},
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {John Doe},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
@MISC{LinkC04,
  author    = {Author Ccc},  
  title     = {Some Title},
  year      = 2004,
  url       = {www.test1.com/bild.jpg},
  keywords  = {bye},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Bibliography, allows section 'uncited references'
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% Cite, \customcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \space 
       \printfield{year}%
       \addcolon\space%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
     }%
   }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  

\begin{document}

\cite{BookB02}

\customcite{customciteentry}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Not cited},notcategory=cited]
\printbibliography[title={Cited},category=cited]
\printbibliography[title={Customcited}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the key to a category in your custom cite command as well, like:

```latex
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{customcited}
% Cite, \customcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \addtocategory{customcited}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \space
       \printfield{year}%
       \addcolon\space%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
     }%
   }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

The question is then how you'd like this category to relate to the `cited` one.  In the MWE below I presumed you wanted the `customcited` ones to be excluded from the other `cited` bibliography.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{customciteentry,
  author    = {Customcite},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
  keywords  = {hello},
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {John Doe},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
@MISC{LinkC04,
  author    = {Author Ccc},
  title     = {Some Title},
  year      = 2004,
  url       = {www.test1.com/bild.jpg},
  keywords  = {bye},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Bibliography, allows section 'uncited references'
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{customcited}
% Cite, \customcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \addtocategory{customcited}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \space
       \printfield{year}%
       \addcolon\space%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
     }%
   }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

\cite{BookB02}

\customcite{customciteentry}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Not cited},notcategory=cited]
\printbibliography[title={Cited},category=cited,notcategory=customcited]
\printbibliography[title={Customcited},category=customcited]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.